# Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api202101.VirtualMachineResourceSettings verify that assembly containing this type is loaded

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

My requirement is moving VM from one region to another using PowerShell script and I'm following this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-powershell

but I am blocked at this step of creating targetResourceSettingsObj due to dependency of  'Az.ResourceMover.private.dll' . I am not getting proper way to add this dependency.

$targetResourceSettingsObj = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api202101.VirtualMachineResourceSettings

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-powershell#:~:text=%24subscriptionId%22-,Add%20resources%20to%20the%20move%20collection,-Retrieve%20the%20IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-powershell#:%7E:text=%24subscriptionId%22-,Add%20resources%20to%20the%20move%20collection,-Retrieve%20the%20IDs)

Tried 1:
PS /home/user> Import-Module AzureAD -Force
Import-Module: Assembly with same name is already loaded PS /home/user> $targetResourceSettingsObj = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api202101.VirtualMachineResourceSettings New-Object: Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api202101.VirtualMachineResourceSettings]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

But it didn't work.

Tried 2:
I tried Add-type -path "Az.ResourceMover.private.dll' It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$targetResourceSettingsObj = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api202101.VirtualMachineResourceSettings.
```

> New-Object: Cannot find type
> Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api202101.VirtualMachineResourceSettings]:
> verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

I also tried to run the same commands in `Azure PowerShell` but am getting the same error as you.

[image]

To resolve the issue, install the following `PowerShell Modules`

```bash
Install-Module Az -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
Import-Module Az -Force
Install-Module -Name Az.ResourceMover -Force
Import-Module -Name Az.ResourceMover
```

Once you have installed the above modules, try all the commands mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-powershell) for moving resources to another region

Create the target resource settings object for the resource you're [moving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-powershell#add-resources-to-the-move-collection) to another region using the below command

Change `Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets API Version` from

```
Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api202101.VirtualMachineResourceSettings
                              to
Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api20210801.VirtualMachineResourceSetting
```

Here is the updated command:

```
$targetResourceSettingsObj = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api20210801.VirtualMachineResourceSettings
```

**Output:**

[image]

To check `Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets` ,follow the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resourcemover/get-azresourcemovermoveresource?view=azps-10.1.0#example-1-get-details-of-all-the-resources-in-the-move-collection)

Comment: I'm getting another error in next step. All the resource exists. VM in source rg, move collection name and rg, target rg. source, movecollection and target are in 3 different regions.

PS> Add-AzResourceMoverMoveResource -ResourceGroupName $MoveResourceGroup -MoveCollectionName $MoveCollectionName -SourceId $VMId -Name $VMToMove -ResourceSetting $targetResourceSettingsObj
: Add-AzResourceMoverMoveResource_CreateExpanded: The resource is not found.
    Possible Causes: The resource doesn't exist or may have been deleted.
    Recommended Action: Retry the operation with a valid resource.

Comment: Kindly check the created movecollection using below command:
Get-AzResourceMoverMoveResource -MoveCollectionName "<MoveCollectionName>" -ResourceGroupName "<RG-MoveCollection-Name>"

Comment: Are you saying it is created even after this error? I don't see anything created in MoveResourceGroup actually. Is this command working for you Add-AzResourceMoverMoveResource ? If you did any modifications can you plz share the script?